# In bash, escaping space chars "\ " no longer works in command arguments

Tags: macos, bash

How it was (and has always been for me):

```
apejoy$ cd Application\ Support  
/Users/apejoy/Library/Application Support  
apejoy$
```

How it is now (and I'm completely baffled):

```
apejoy$ cd Application\ Support  
-bash: cd: Application: No such file or directory  
/Users/apejoy/Library
```

What the heck? Regardless of my escaped [space] char, bash is stopping at the escape char, looking for an Application directory, which does not exist in `/Users/apejoy/Library`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you now have a function named `cd` that intercepts your invocations of `cd` to do some extra processing and the function is not properly quoting the argument(s) it sends to the `cd` built-in. Execute the following at a bash prompt and see what you get.

```
type cd
```